# TypeError: items.forEach is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**I need to solve the error that you see on the screen, I already tried with .map and with foreach, even so my object is not traversed, I am clear that .map is only for Arrays but anyway I tried, An example of what I try to go through is in the console.**

here a example of my object

```
    {
        OKaY30PcZOXBZngSLX33:
    {
        birthDate: U {seconds: 1622469668, nanoseconds: 156000000}
        dni: "27347106"
        email: "alew140@gmail.com"
        firstName: "Alejandro"
        gender: 0
        lastName: "Pereira"
        phone: "04144117131"
        specialty: ""
    }
        UuynMRMJ9G85Ty9Ayln0:
      {
        birthDate: U {seconds: 1622469780, nanoseconds: 932000000}
        dni: "27347106"
        email: "alew140@gmail.com"
        firstName: "Alejandro"
        gender: 0
        lastName: "Pereira"
        phone: "04144117131"
        specialty: ""
      }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Note questions must be posted in English and include a [mre]. But most likely items is not an array.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

forEach works with Array, not objects.

Comment: are you sure ? not is reverse ? go try with 
Object.Keys(obj)
and
Object.values(obj)

Comment: take a look on Array API 
you can use this one for your object 

Object.entries(items).forEach(item => {
  console.log(item)
})